# How to solve this 1st order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x^2 + 3y^2 - 7}{3x^2 + 4y^2 + 8}$$

This does not satisfy the exactness and I can't find any integrating factor to transform it. I can't make it homogeneous too.

Thanks in advance for the replies.

edit: The question was written incorrectly by the instructor, so in this version there is no analytic solution for it.

Comment: Do you mind telling in what context this ODE appeared? It looks difficult to solve.

Comment: That was a standard homework question given to solve for its general solution by reducing to one of the standard forms (separable, linear, Bernoulli etc). I have tried every way to solve it but I can't find any analytic solution unfortunately, I guess that the question can be wrong or be written incorrectly by the instructor. I will ask it tomorrow and update here immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see any way of getting an analytic solution. But it is easy to get numerical solutions. For example taking $y_0=0$ we get:

[image]

Comment: I agree that probably there is no analytic solution, but for convenience I will ask it tomorrow to the instructor who gave it as homework. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Yes, the question has no analytic solution, I asked to instructor and he corrected the question which is now an easy exact equation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the method in http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=164:

Let $u=\dfrac{y}{x}$ ,

Then $y=xu$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x\dfrac{du}{dx}+u$

$\therefore x\dfrac{du}{dx}+u=\dfrac{2x^2+3(xu)^2-7}{3x^2+4(xu)^2+8}$

$x\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{(3u^2+2)x^2-7}{(4u^2+3)x^2+8}-u$

$x\dfrac{du}{dx}=-\dfrac{(4u^3-3u^2+3u-2)x^2+8u+7}{(4u^2+3)x^2+8}$

$((4u^3-3u^2+3u-2)x^2+8u+7)\dfrac{dx}{du}=-(4u^2+3)x^3-8x$

Let $v=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{du}=-\dfrac{2}{x^3}\dfrac{dx}{du}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{((4u^3-3u^2+3u-2)x^2+8u+7)x^3}{2}\dfrac{dv}{du}=-(4u^2+3)x^3-8x$

$\left(\dfrac{8u+7}{x^2}+4u^3-3u^2+3u-2\right)\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{8}{x^4}+\dfrac{4u^2+3}{x^2}$

$((8u+7)v+4u^3-3u^2+3u-2)\dfrac{dv}{du}=8v^2+(4u^2+3)v$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.